# Am I making a video with 24 fps or 7 fps?

Tags: ffmpeg, fps

I entered the following code to make a 24 fps video:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i a%04d.jpg video.webm
```

I noticed that it's written fps=7.3 at the button of the screen and I feel like they are the actual specs of the output video. Is it really 7.3 fps? Or 24 fps?

[image]

Comment: It is 24. The fps=7.3 is the current rate that it is encoding. There is a duplicate question of this somewhere...

Comment: @llogan From your comment, I think the number 7.3 should be 24 most of the time. But it doesn't change, it's 7.3 all the time. I think this means that the current rate of any part of the video will be 7.3 or in other words it'll be 7.3 for the whole video (not 24). Am I right?

Comment: The final video will be 24 fps. Your machine can only process about 7.3 frames per second (libvpx-vp9 is slow). That's as fast as it can go with the current command and input. It has nothing to do with the fps of the output file. It is just for informational purposes to tell you how fast your computer is currently encoding the file.

Comment: @llogan Oh thank you so much for your explanation. I would consider this comment as the best answer if you wrote it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The output video will be 24 fps

The `fps=7.3` at the bottom of the console output is indicating the number of frames that are currently being processed. `ffmpeg` tries to encode as fast as it can, but 7.3 fps is as fast as your computer can go with the current command and input.

It is not the fps of the output file. It is just for informational purposes to tell you how fast your computer is currently encoding the file.